# Find the first n elements of one vector which contain all the elements of another vector

Tags: r, vector, subset

Given two vectors `vecA` and `vecB`, I would like to find the smallest `n` such that

```r
all(vecB %in% vecA[1:n])
```

is `TRUE`.

This is in a tight inner loop, so speed would be good. Obviously I could do

```r
n <- NA_integer_ 
for (i in seq_along(vecA)) {
  if (all(vecB %in% vecA[1:i])) {
    n <- i
    break
  } 
}
```

but is there a faster/more elegant way?

One thing you can use: `vecB` is always going to be a sequence of the form `1:M`.

Here's an example where `n` should equal 5:

```r
vecB <- 1:3
vecA <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be:

```
max(match(vecB, vecA))
```

Results for different situations:

```
vecB <- 1:3
vecA <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2)

[1] 5

vecB <- 1:3
vecA <- c(3, 2, 2, 1)

[1] 4

vecB <- 1:3
vecA <- c(2, 2, 1)

[1] NA
```

Comment: It seems to work but I don't understand why. (Thinking noises.)

Comment: OK, I get it. If any of `vecB` don't match, we get `NA`. Correct. If all of `vecB` match, then the last element which is the (first) match of any element is the first element where all have been matched.

Comment: Your interpretation is correct :) I'm still thinking about edge cases when it wouldn't work.

Comment: It's in my package now, so if you hit one, better tell me :-)

Answer (score 0):

One solution (though) but logical translation may be

```r
vecB <- 1:3
vecA <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2)


min(seq_along(vecA)[sapply(Reduce(function (.x, .y) union(.x, .y), vecA, accumulate = T), 
                           function(x) all(vecB %in% x))])
#> [1] 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: this can be much shorter in purrr